# Log flexlm licence usage from remote machine

Tags: python, flexlm

We have several software packages (SolidWorks, Pro/ENGINEER, OrCAD, Minitab... ) that use FlexLM to manage network licences.

I have written a python program to poll the FlexLM daemons every few mintues using `lmutil lmstat -a`.

However, this requires `lmutil` to be installed on the same machine as the python program.

Our FlexLM licence daemons are on several servers so does anyone know how to connect to a FlexLM server over its port to ask for its licence usage state?

Comment: On the *ARM Information Centre* I found a page with a couple of perl scripts for parsing the output of lmutil - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4037.html - which may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the only way to get licence usage over a network is to poll the flexlm daemon using:

```
lmutil lmstat -a -c <port-number@license-server>
```

I've not marked orenhg's repsonse as an answer as it is advertising his product rather than answering the question.

Comment: lmutil is optionnal in this line. `<port-number@license-server>` may be replaced by a filename describing the licence.